# Shortcode won't execute

Tags: php, shortcode

I've created a shortcode using my limited knowledge, google, and stackexchange to do so.

But when I load the page, it loads above the page contents and appears as html text.

```
(shortocode text)
-------
page contents appearing normally
```

As I've said, I have limited (Zero) knowledge of this type of coding and I'm unable to find out which part/what isn't working.

I've attached a compacted version of the code I've used, with less content being displayed in the shortcode function.

```
// Add Shortcode
function p_formatage( $atts , $content = null ) {

    // Attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'postid' => '',
            'ptitle' => '',
            'pimage' => '',
        ), $atts )
    );

    $postid = $atts['postid'];
    $ptitle = $atts['ptitle'];
    $pimage = $atts['pimage'];

    // Post title
    $p-ptitle = if ( empty( $ptitle ) ) {
    echo "Whoops! Looks like went wrong here!";
    }
    else { 
     if ( $postid == true ) {
     echo "<span class="ptitle"><a href="http://www.website.com/' . $postid . '">' . $ptitle . '</a></span>";
     }
     else { 
     echo "<span class="ptitle">' . $ptitle . '</span>";
     }
    }

    $p-beta = if ( empty( $pimage) ) {
    echo "$ptitle";
    }
    else { 
    echo "<span class="pimage"><img href="http://www.website.com/xx.jpg";/></span>";
    }

   $pclass = if ( $postid ) {
    echo "$p-ptitle";
    }
    else { 
    echo "$p-beta";
    }

    // Output
    $output = {
        echo "$pclass";
    }

    return $output;
}

add_shortcode( 'p-fmt', 'p_formatage' );
```

Comment: Please format your code properly and paste those here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using your shortcode function to directly output something (using `echo`). Shortcodes are supposed to *return* the desired output rather than echo it directly. You could use [output buffering](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to "catch" anything that's outputted (for example, via `echo`) in an output buffer instead of directly outputting it, and retrieve the content of the buffer afterwards.

This would yield an implementation like this:

```
function wpse149825_my_shortcode( $atts, $content = NULL ) {
    // Turn on output buffering, which sends output from "echo" to a "buffer" instead of directly outputting it
    ob_start();

    // Output shortcode content
    echo 'Shortcode content';

    // Get buffer contents
    $contents = ob_get_clean();

    // Return shortcode content
    return $contents; 
}

add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode', 'wpse149825_my_shortcode' );
```

Comment: I understand the logic, but how do you use the buffer on multiple echo $value?

Comment: The buffer basically catches *anything* that's outputted. So, using multiple echos inbetween `ob_start` and `ob_get_clean` are all "caught" in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You need fix the echo statements which are breaking in between. Also, as rightly said by @engelen above, don't directly echo the output. Make it buffer and "return" it.

Here is the code which will help.

```
<?php
// Add Shortcode
function p_formatage( $atts, $content = null ) {

    // Attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'postid' => '',
                'ptitle' => '',
                'pimage' => '',
            ),
            $atts,
            'p-fmt'
        )
    );

    $postid = $atts['postid'];
    $ptitle = $atts['ptitle'];
    $pimage = $atts['pimage'];

    // Start buffering the output
    ob_start();

    /* ------ DO WHATEVER OUTPUT YOU WANT TO DISPLAY BELOW THIS -------- */

    // Post title
    if ( empty( $ptitle ) ) {
        echo 'Whoops! Looks like went wrong here!';
    } else {
        if ( $postid == true ) {
            echo '<span class="ptitle"><a href="http://www.website.com/' . $postid . '">' . $ptitle . '</a></span>';
        } else {
            echo '<span class="ptitle">' . $ptitle . '</span>';
        }
    }

    /* ------ STOP SPITING OUT THE OUTPUT NOW  ------------------------ */

    // Get buffer contents
    $contents = ob_get_clean();

    // Return shortcode content
    return $contents;
}
add_shortcode( 'p-fmt', 'p_formatage' );
```

Comment: In your code above, a single $value has been turned into `$contents` output. But what if you have multiple $value echoing code, like `$p-ptitle = if` was, how would you go about it? – Would it be recommended to turn them into functions?

Comment: Yes, Keep using echo multiple times like I have shown above, provided all the `echo`, `print` etc. must be used before this line `$contents = ob_get_clean();`. This way, all the values will be inside `$contents`and will be displayed on frontend too.  :)

Comment: If the echo codes start with a value like `$p_ptitle = if ( whatever..)`, do they need to be formatted differently? Would they now need to begin by `if ( whatever..)` and end with `$p_ptitle = ob_get_contents();`

Comment: I don't clearly understand why do you want to assign the value returned from an `if( whatever... )` condition check, to a variable ? Simply use this conditions etc. to check and echo what needs to be displayed in place of the `[short-code]`.

Comment: Hey @Subharanjan I've created some code in the original question to help you see. The shortcode is made of multiple echoes, that create different $values, which are combined at the end to create the final output of the shortcode.